# How do you really hide and show a tab bar when tapping on part of your view? (no buttons but any location of the screen)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, tabbar, uitabcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchHandled))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


}


@objc func touchHandled() {
    tabBarController?.hideTabBarAnimated(hide: true)
}


extension UITabBarController {
    func hideTabBarAnimated(hide:Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            if hide {
                self.tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 100)
            } else {
                self.tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -100)
            }
        })
    }
```

}

I can only hide the tab bar but I can't make it show when you tap again. I tried to look for answers on stack overflow but the answers seems to only work if you're using a button or a storyboard.

Comment: At a guess, I would suggest that you need a flag which can be flipped between `true` and `false` when `touchHandled` is called, which would determine if the tab bar should be hidden or shown

Comment: Do you want to know the tap in any part of a view controller? lets say user taps with in (100 x 100) from (X, Y) point, do you want to hide the tab bar?

Comment: The tapping could be any part of a view controller. Yes, I would like to hide the tab after a tap. And then, show the tab bar again after another tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a variable `isTabBarHidden` in class which stores if the tabBar has been animated to hide. (You could have used tabBar.isHidden, but that would complicate the logic a little bit when animate hiding and showing)

```
class ViewController {

    var isTabBarHidden = false // set the default value as required

    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchHandled))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func touchHandled() {
        guard let tabBarControllerFound = tabBarController else {
            return
        }
        tabBarController?.hideTabBarAnimated(hide: !isTabBarHidden)
        isTabBarHidden = !isTabBarHidden
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer worked! Rakesha, I would like to thank you very much for putting the effort in helping me this question! Hope you'll become a teacher someday.

Answer (score 0):

Generalised solution with protocol  which will work in all the screens

Create `UIViewController` named `BaseViewController` and make it base class of all of your view controllers

Now Define protocol

```
protocol ProtocolHideTabbar:class {
    func hideTabbar ()

}
protocol ProtocolShowTabbar:class {
    func showTabbar ()

}

extension ProtocolHideTabbar  where Self : UIViewController {
    func hideTabbar () {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
extension ProtocolShowTabbar  where Self : UIViewController {
    func showTabbar () {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

By default we want show tabbar in every view controller so

```
extension UIViewController : ProtocolShowTabbar {}
```

In your BaseView Controller

in view will appear method add following code to show hide based on protocol

```
    if self is ProtocolHideTabbar {
        ( self as! ProtocolHideTabbar).hideTabbar()
    } else  if  self is ProtocolShowTabbar{
        ( self as ProtocolShowTabbar).showTabbar()

    }
```

**How to use**

Simply

```
class YourViewControllerWithTabBarHidden:BaseViewController,ProtocolHideTabbar {
}
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Hey brother, Thank you for trying to answer my question. Unfortunately, I think I made my question confusing, sorry. I meant to ask on how to show and hide a tab bar when tapping anywhere on my current view. I'm able to hide the tab bar with my current view when I tap anywhere. But when I tap again, it doesn't show the tab bar. It remains hidden.

I would like to show the tab bar again but it seems like swift is processing the first tap only.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested 100% working**

Please try below code for that in `UITabBarController` subclass

```
 var isTabBarHidden:Bool = false


 func setTabBarHidden(_ tabBarHidden: Bool, animated: Bool,completion:((Void) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if tabBarHidden == isTabBarHidden   {

            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            //check tab bar is visible and view and window height is same then it should be 49 + window Heigth

            if (tabBarHidden == true && UIScreen.main.bounds.height == self.view.frame.height) {
                let offset = self.tabBar.frame.size.height
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height + offset)

            }

            if let block = completion {

                block()
            }
            return
        }
        let offset: CGFloat? = tabBarHidden ? self.tabBar.frame.size.height : -self.tabBar.frame.size.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animated ? 0.250 : 0.0, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [.curveEaseIn, .layoutSubviews], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.tabBar.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.tabBar.center.x), y: CGFloat(self.tabBar.center.y + offset!))

            //Check if View is already at bottom so we don't want to move view more up (it will show black screen on bottom ) Scnario : When  present mail app
            if (Int(offset!) <= 0 && UIScreen.main.bounds.height ==   self.view.frame.height) == false {
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height + offset!)
            }
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: { _ in
            if let block = completion {
                block()
            }
        })
        isTabBarHidden = tabBarHidden
    }
```

Hope it is helpful